# Creating, Populating, and Deleting Entries in an Array or Dictionary using VBA for Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary, populate

I am new to VBA, but I have spent ample time searching for a bit of code to help solve my situation which is as follows:

For simplicity I will illustrate what I am trying to accomplish with an example:

Say I have a pile of marbles with a unique number and I want to place them into numbered categories.

For example:

```
At "Time '1.0'" "Marble '1'" is "Categorized" into "Group '1'"   
At "Time '2.0'" "Marble '2'" is "Categorized" into "Group '2'" etc. 
At "Time '3.0'" "Marble '1'" is "Categorized" into "Group '3'"
```

Hence At Time 3.0 Marble 1 is Categorized both as Group 1 and Group 2.

I created a button that would allow me to enter the "Marble #" and "Time" and report whether or not at the given time the Marble was Categorized, if so What Group, If not what was the last Group it was in.

This worked fine when the Marble was only ever Categorized into 1 Group, but when the case arose where a Marble was Categorized into multiple Groups and then removed from one of the Groups, i.e.

............At "Time '4.0'" "Marble '1'" is "UnCategorized" from "Group '1'"

my limited code would delete any record of Categorization and simply report the most recent Categorization as "the last Category it was in" i.e.

Marble # = 1, Time = 5.0    Result = "Uncategorized" Last Category = "Group '1'" When In fact it is still "Categorized" as "Group '2'".

In Summary I need a code that will allow me to enter the "Marble #" and the "Time" and tell me if at that specific time the "Marble" is "Categorized", if so which "Group" is it "Categorized" to and if not then what was the last "Group" it was "Categorized" to.

I have posted my code below. . Please keep in mind that this is my first VBA code and it has been Frankensteined together via Google Search and trial and error. . . ****(Note Cell(15,8) and Cell (18,8) are "Enter Marble #" and "Enter Time" Respectively)****(Columns 1, 2, 3, 4 are Marble #, Categorization, Group #, and Time Respectively)****

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim Categorized As String, i As Integer, Group As Integer

Count = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))

For i = 1 To Count 

    If Cells (i, 1).Value = Cells(15, 8) And Cells (i, 4).Value <= Cells (18, 8) And Cells (i, 2) = "CATEGORIZE"  Then Categorized = "CATEGORIZED" 

    If Cells (i, 1).Value = Cells(15, 8) And Cells (i, 4).Value <= Cells (18, 8) And Cells (i, 2) = "UNCATEGORIZE"  Then Categorized = "NOT CATEGORIZED"

    If Cells (i, 1).Value = Cells(15, 8) And Cells (i, 4).Value <= Cells (18, 8) And Cells (i, 2) = "CATEGORIZE"  Then Group = Cells(i, 3)

Next i

    If Categorized = "CATEGORIZED" Then MsgBox Categorized & " Categorized to " & Group
    If Categorized = "NOT CATEGORIZED" Then Msgbox Categorized & " Was Last Categorized to " & Group
    If Categorized = "" Then Msgbox "Marble Does Not Exist Prior to This Time"

End Sub
```

Also, There are multiple duplicate entries at different times i.e.

```
At "Time '1.0'" "Marble '1'" is "Categorized" into "Group '1'"
At "Time '1.1'" "Marble '1'" is "Categorized" into "Group '1'" 
At "Time '1.4'" "Marble '1'" is "Categorized" into "Group '1'"
```

The number of duplicate "Categorizations" does not concern me it is either "Categorized" or "UnCategorized" . . . (Regardless of how many times you push an "on" button, if you press the "off" button the light goes off :))

Your help is greatly appreciated. Please keep criticism constructive as I have mentioned this is my first VBA code Ever. Thank you.

Comment: I think you should look at the Dictionary` object. A great reference by Patrick Matthews [Using the Dictionary Class in VBA](http://www.experts-exchange.com/A_3391.html)

Comment: I'd avoid using Count and Group as variable names - they both exist elsewhere in the VBA Object Library. I use intCount or lngCount (for variable type Integer or Long) to keep things clear. You'll also need to amend `Count = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))` to `Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))`. Does the code break in a particular place?

Comment: Thanks for the Dictionary Link. I will look into it and see if I am able to make any more progress. I will also take your advise MattCrum and change the variable names to clean it up. To answer your question I have not intentionally made a code break. I plan to just have two entries ("Marble # and Time) then push the command button for the code to run and display the results.